# How to find basket of stocks that are the inverse of yet another or ETF (never short)?

Tags: portfolio-management

Suppose want to long an *inverse* of an ETF, rather than short the ETF itself.  Is there a way to determine some mix of component stocks that would mimic the returns of such an inverse ETF (where also have the constraint that don't want any of the weights of the component stocks of this inverse to be negative either)? 
Also, what would be a better way to phrase this problem as to give some better google results to look into?

Comment: In practice it is very difficult or impossible to find a set of stocks that are highly negatively correlated to another group of stocks. So inverse ETFs have to be short.

Comment: The only exception to this is if you want to short an inverse ETF :) i say this because OP did not put any constraint on the nature of the target ETF so we should not make the assumption that this ETF is a plain vanilla long stock index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A basket of stocks which is *long-only* will always have a positive *beta* to the market.

Shorting this basket will therefore mean you seek another portfolio with a negative beta.

As per the first remark this impossible to achieve synthetically with a long only portfolio.

Q.E.D.